# Error when trying to run a Play Scala app with sbt after fresh install on Catalina: "Error loading JNotify watch service: null"

Tags: java, playframework, macos-catalina, adoptopenjdk, jnotify

After moving to Catalina and re-installing everything, no way to run my Play Scala app.

After doing `sbt` then `run`, I get this error:

```
[warn] Error loading JNotify watch service: null
```

Everything was installed with brew from this brewfile (I didn't paste the complete file):

```
tap "AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk"

# Mac apps
cask "adoptopenjdk8"

brew "sbt@0.13"
brew "jenv"
```

**Java version:**

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_242-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

**sbt:** 0.13.18
**play:** 2.6.20
**os x:** 10.15.3 (19D76)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't technically explain why JNotify is not working well on your environment but I can definitely say it's linked to the latest update of openjdk8.

So I succeeded to reproduce the issue with `adoptopenjdk8` version `242`, my workaround is to uninstall this version of openjdk and force brew to install a previous version (232) :

`brew cask install "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AdoptOpenJDK/homebrew-openjdk/19d716f1c9ebc325ed23c5df580e0d2b027285a1/Casks/adoptopenjdk8.rb"`

Comment: It seems to be this bug (a result of them breaking a workaround whilst fixing another bug): https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8240521

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue. The above answer helped me. A slightly easier approach for me was instead of uninstalling the current version, I installed 8.0.232.fx-zulu using sdk man. Made this version default. It worked.

commands:

sdk list java
sdk install java 8.0.232.fx-zulu
make it default: y

Build and run your app.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @rsefuril. I had the same issue. I had adoptopenjdk8 version 242, installing openjdk version "1.8.0_232" fixed the issue.
But I installed graalvm. This link shows how to install graalvm to macos.
Download graalvm from here https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/tag/vm-19.3.0

1. I downloaded https://github.com/graalvm/graalvm-ce-builds/releases/download/vm-19.3.0/graalvm-ce-java8-darwin-amd64-19.3.0.tar.gz
2. Then extract the file and move the extracted folder

   > sudo mv ~/Downloads/graalvm-ce-java8-19.3.0 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
3. Add following line to ~/.zprofile file:
   export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
4. Then check if java version is correct:

   > java -version

openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-20191009173705.graal.jdk8u-src-tar-gz-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit GraalVM CE 19.3.0 (build 25.232-b07-jvmci-19.3-b05, mixed mode)

That's it.

PS: You may need to delete previous Java 1.8 from system. I deleted it by removing folders from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/